# What happens if you delete a question OR answer with negative or 0 scores

Tags: support, downvotes, deleted-questions, deleted-answers

What happens if you voluntarily removes a question or answer frequently?

Assume that you posted a question. Some people have down voted it. Is it OK to remove the question by yourself instead of other experts closing it?

Assume that you posted an answer. Immediately you realized that the answer is not useful or already present by some other expert or answer is not right fit to the question. Is it OK to remove your answer by yourself?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you asking because you have a lot of negative or 0-scored content that you want to delete? You might want to consider improving the ones that can be improved instead, because of the possibility of getting a question/answer ban. Depends on how good your contributions have been overall, however. If you've contributed hundreds of positive scoring posts, deleting a few negative scoring ones probably won't do anything negative to you.

Comment: On average, I am getting at least one upvote per day on 100+ posts in one month.  I have deleted around 3-4 answers & 3-4 questions till now

Comment: That sounds just fine...how much more content were you looking to delete?

Comment: Nothing much as of now. May be 1 or 2 if they have been down voted.

Answer (score 3):

If your questions or answers have a 0 or negative score, then the community consensus is that they are not useful. In such a case, it is OK to delete them yourself. **Note, however, that if you frequently delete too much of your own content, then you may incur a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) or [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans) ban.**

If your questions or answers have a *positive*, non-zero score, however, then the community consensus is that they are useful, and it is generally frowned upon to delete them in those cases, especially for particularly high-scoring posts.

If you do not wish to be the owner of content with a positive score, you may contact the Stack Overflow team through [their contact form](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact), and request that the content be disassociated from your account, in which case the content remains in its current undeleted state, but is no longer associated with any particular user.

Comment: Is it a Q/A ban if you delete a lot of content? I thought it raised an automatic mod flag in case of rage quitting?

Comment: @jonrsharpe not a 100% sure.  According to [question-bans](http://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans), "*users are only banned if they have a significant number of heavily down-voted, zero-voted, or deleted posts*".